# Cloud Function writing wrong time on firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

When I write a `Timestamp` on Firestore it shows `6.00PM` on database though I have not defined any time in the Date object.

My Approach to get `Timestamp` from date :

```js
let reservationDate = new Date(year,month,dayOfMonth);

let bookedRoomData = {
      ....
      ...
      reservationDate: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(reservationDate),
      ...
    };
```

What is the reason behind showing `6.00PM` instead of `12.00AM` ?
What should be done to fix this?

Screenshot of database is given bellow -

[image: Screenshot Of Database]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged this google-cloud-functions, I'm assuming that your code is running in Cloud Functions.

When you create a new Date object on any machine, it uses the local machine's sense of timezone.  So you're making a date at midnight in whatever timezone has been assigned to your Cloud Functions instance.  It's not the timezone where you're computer's clock is set.

When you see a timestamp in the console, it's always going to appear on your computer's clock's configured timezone.  So, your computer is 6 hours behind whatever is being used by Cloud Functions.

If you want a specific time, you should make sure your Date is configured that way.  Consider using a library such as [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) to create dates according to timezones of your interest.  Bear in mind that Timestamp objects do not encode a timezone.  They just render in the console according to your local timezone.